# How to get app port from IIS Express in C#

Tags: c#, iis-express, directoryentry, servermanager

I am trying to get The port which an app is running on, from IIS Express.

So far i tried those two approaches:

```
//first
var iisExpress = new DirectoryEntry("IIS://localhost/W3SVC/AppPools").Children;

//second
var mgr = new ServerManager().Sites;
```

But both give me only the `DefaultAppPool` with the `Default Web App`, while what i need is the apps i'm running localy from Visual Studio.

Comment: Where do you run that piece of code, in the hosted web app or somewhere else?

Answer (score 0):

This will output the names and ports of all your websites running on IIS.

```
var serverManager = new ServerManager();
    
foreach (Site site in serverManager.Sites)
{
   Console.WriteLine(site.Name);
   Console.WriteLine(site.Bindings[0].EndPoint.Port);
}
```

If you want to save the port of a specific site (ex: MyWebsite) on a variable you can do the following:

```
var serverManager = new ServerManager();
var mySite = serverManager.Sites.FirstOrDefault(s => s.Name.Contains("MyWebsite"));
int myPort = mySite?.Bindings[0].EndPoint.Port ?? 0;
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. but as i mentioned, i already tried it. i'm only getting the "Default Web Site" and not the app i'm running from Visual Studio.

Comment: In my case the the first block of code outputs 3 sites even though I have more, however DefaultAppPool doesn't show up for me.
I did notice that the 3 that have ports also have 1 or more Applications in the Application Pools tab and DefaultAppPool has 0 Applications.
Can you check if the website you're trying to get the port from has any Application in the Application Pools tab and that it status is started ?

Comment: I'm not sure what is the 'Application Pools tab' you are referring to. On debugging, when i look into `serverManager` properties, there is only one pool - `DefaultAppPool`, which contains one site - `Default Web Site`.